# Problems in API Platform and MariaDB with enum when you trying to do reverse enginering with Symfony [2,3,4]?

Tags: symfony, mariadb, api-platform.com

If you have an API Platform installed and working and you have to an exists project with full filled database (MariaDB)... Probably you need to create Entities from existing tables (reverse enginering). To this, you may run:

```
bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle php
```

Acording to the [oficial Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html)

The result is a big error...

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                                                      
  Unknown database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL57Platform may not support it.
```

Answer (score 0):

What we need to do is edit the app/config/config.yml and add the following lines:

```
mapping_types:
  enum: string
```

The file looks like this:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: UTF8  
        mapping_types:
          enum: string
```

Credits to Stof in the following [link](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/866)